# Jaxb не парсит амперсант & в текстовом поле?

Tags: java, spring, jaxb

Приложение на spring, со слоями web, business и persistence.

Контроллер принимает на вход xml в запросах, парсит их используя jaxb и передает на слой бизнес.

Контроллер выглядит так:

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes = {"application/xml"}, produces = {"application/xml"})
        public String add(@RequestBody User user, (value = "id", required = false) String id) {
            String result = service.add(users, id);
            return result;
        }
```

jaxb сущность:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements Serializable {
    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    @Size(max = 25)
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "idAuthor")
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String idAuthor;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Comments")
    @XmlElement(name = "comment")
    private String comment;
}
```

Но, когда в поле comment присылают не просто текст, а содержащий амперсан & - получаю ошибку валидации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&`, как и `<` `>` и различные кавычки - невалидные символы для xml, нужно использовать `&amp;` `&lt;` `&gt;`